# how to know a process's group in android

Tags: android, shell

Is there a tool to show a process in which groups in android? such as: in adb shell:

type> id
uid=2000(shell) gid=2000(shell) **groups=1003(graphics),1004(input),1007(log),1009(mount),1011(adb),1015(sdcard_rw),1028(sdcard_r),3001(net_bt_admin)**

but I wish to see some of processes, such as mediaserver.

I know when an android app launched, you can find the the gids in adb log, such as:

Start proc com.test.app for activity com.test.app/.MainActivity: pid=22565 uid=10102 gids={1015, 3003}

com.test.app has been in group 1015 and 3003.

I don't know there is some way to see such info of running process.

Answer (score 14):

To determine the groups of a process you just need the process id as listed in `adb shell ps`, for example:

```
USER     PID   PPID  VSIZE  RSS     WCHAN    PC         NAME
u0_a33    7295  116   664448 42412 ffffffff 4019aee4 S com.android.systemui
```

Then do `cat /proc/{pid}/status` and look for the the `Groups` section:

```
 $ cat /proc/7295/status                                         
Name:   ndroid.systemui
State:  S (sleeping)
Tgid:   7295
Pid:    7295
PPid:   116
TracerPid:  0
Uid:    10033   10033   10033   10033
Gid:    10033   10033   10033   10033
FDSize: 256
Groups: 1015 1028 3001 3002 50033 
VmPeak:   665892 kB
VmSize:   664200 kB
VmLck:         0 kB
VmHWM:     42564 kB
VmRSS:     42420 kB
VmData:    20000 kB
VmStk:       136 kB
VmExe:         8 kB
VmLib:     34296 kB
VmPTE:       140 kB
VmSwap:        0 kB
Threads:    15
SigQ:   0/7766
SigPnd: 0000000000000000
ShdPnd: 0000000000000000
SigBlk: 0000000000001204
SigIgn: 0000000000000000
SigCgt: 00000002000094e8
CapInh: 0000000000000000
CapPrm: 0000000000000000
CapEff: 0000000000000000
CapBnd: ffffffffffffffff
Cpus_allowed:   f
Cpus_allowed_list:  0-3
voluntary_ctxt_switches:    707
nonvoluntary_ctxt_switches: 3019
```

Look at [android_filesystem_config.h](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/master/include/private/android_filesystem_config.h) in AOSP system/core to see what the group ids mean. For example `1015` is `AID_SDCARD_RW`.

Comment: please help to check my question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37186761/check-android-process-groups