# check android process groups

Tags: android, runtime-permissions

Device: android 6.0.1

I wrote an app, use `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission in manifest, install this app, and then turn on storage permission for this app from settings.

```
adb shell
:/ # ps | grep com.amida.test
u0_a199   6722  477   872572 41084 SyS_epoll_ b6c89c74 S com.amida.test
:/ # cat /proc/6722/status
Name:    com.amida.test
State:    S (sleeping)
Tgid:    6722
Ngid:    0
Pid:    6722
PPid:    477
TracerPid:    0
Uid:    10199    10199    10199    10199
Gid:    10199    10199    10199    10199
FDSize:    256
Groups:    9997 50199
```

Question: I think groups should has 1015. but can not find 1015 there， why?

according to : `#define AID_SDCARD_RW     1015`

More information:

In Android pre-M, from /etc/permissions/platform.xml, we can find bellow information:

```
    <permission name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" >
    <group gid="sdcard_r" />
    <group gid="sdcard_rw" />
</permission>

#define AID_SDCARD_RW     1015
```

If app use permission "android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE", then the app's process has groups: 1015. ([as per android_filesystem_config.h](http://androidxref.com/6.0.1_r10/xref/system/core/include/private/android_filesystem_config.h#57))

but on Android M, firstly, I can not find the permission(WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) and gid mapping configration. because files in sdcard belongs to sdcard_rw group, then how can the app read and write sdcard? (I think Android use Linux permission system for read&write files, right?)

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? can give some context to understand???

Comment: I update the question, Thanks!

Comment: 1) Why are you expecting a new Android version to keep that same system? and 2) Why does this matter for application development?

Comment: @m0skit0, Yes, it doesn't matter for application development, I just want to know how android M permission system handle this.

Comment: @user1890874 whats PID you are trying in command cat /proc/[PID]/status, is it for your app, where did you find pid for your app?

Comment: @shridutt updated question, thanks.

Comment: yes you are right, hv a look at http://www.all-things-android.com/content/deeper-look-android-application-permissions